# Cannot open cmd.exe

Tags: windows

When executing cmd.exe the window semi appears for a fraction of a second then disappears. I recently added a new drive and have been reinstalling software on it when I can.

I tried:

1. repairing windows
2. running sfc.exe /scannow in PowerShell CLI
3. adding a reg key that supposedly prevents disabling cmd (my machine is not under a group policy and i removed the key after trying it).
4. i reinstalled windows while keeping apps etc..

Also slightly worrying is the look of my registry, I have included an image, I don't know if it relates to my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions :

-run cmd as administrator

-Update your OS to latest version

-re-create your user profile

or

Perform system restore to the day it works.